# How to avoid group_concat separator duplicate in mysql select result

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

I have 2 tables call record and user, their fields are below

**record** fields:

> - recordID (key)
> - userID   (key)

**user** fields:

> - userID (key)
> - userName
> - userNote

and I want to know recordID, userName, userNote group by recordID
Here is my sql

```
 select record.recordID, group_concat(user.userName) as USERNAMES , group_concat(user.userNote) as USERNOTES from record 
 left outer join user on record.userID = user.USERID  
 group by record.recordID
```

now I can split USERNAMES and USERNOTES with ',' to know every username and his usernote

But If there is a ',' in userNote ,It might make mistakes

for example, BEN userNote is nice,tall  and TOM's userNote is nice

the sql result will be

> USERNAMES-> BEN,TOM
>
> USERNOTES-> nice,tall,nice

In this case USERNOTES will have 3 notes, I can't differ from which one is TOM'S note

Is there any way to avoid this situation?

Or the best way I can do is use a separator that is hard to appear, like '！＠＃＠！'

In my real case, I have 10 tables related to a key, so if I left outer join all tables, it will be tons of duplicate rows,

Comment: It would help to answer if you provide some example data, and the result returned by your query

Answer (score 2):

One method is a different separator:

```
select r.recordID,
       group_concat(u.userName separator ';') as USERNAMES ,   
       group_concat(u.userNote separator ';') as USERNOTES
from record r left outer join
     user u
     on r.userID = u.USERID  
group by r.recordID ;
```